# Wifi driver for Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I've got 'DW1503 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card' installed on my new Dell notebook and since I prefer to used Linux than Windows I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine.
The installation was painless althou OS doesn't recognize my network card.
Where can I find network  card drivers for Ubuntu (I could only find drivers for various Win releases) and how can I install them? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HW manufacturers simply do not provide drivers for all OSes for their devices, and/or contributing developers have not been able to write drivers for all devices.  Normally, you are better off selecting HW that is known to have drivers for your OS, rather than buying HW and then trying to find drivers.

You might try configuring the Ubuntu *Update Manager* to search alternate 3rd party sites for drivers.

If that doesn't turn up a driver, then there are [a wiki for Dell Wireless 1503 WLAN Half Mini-Card](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Dell_Wireless_1503_WLAN_Half_Mini-Card), [a driver for the Broadcom chip](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211), and [Broadcom's Linux driver](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)  Note that Broadcom claims that its driver has already been compiled and should be in the Ubuntu package repository; you could try searching for the "Broadcom Linux hybrid wireless driver" using the *Synaptic Package Manager*.

Comment: After some more digging I've found a solution. Thanks for the links. They were quite helpful.